# Get rows of data but with limited number of related table rows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create my first project in Laravel. I have tables `urls` and `reviews`, every url has many reviews. In index view I would like to list all urls with their latest 2 reviews.

**model Url**

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}
```

**model Review**

```
public function url()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Url');
}
```

**class UrlController**

```
class UrlController extends Controller
{
        public function index()
        {

           // here I would need to get all urls with latest two reviews for each url
           $urls = URL::all();
           return view('urls.index')->with('urls', $urls);

        }
    }
```

**view Index**

```
   @foreach ($urls as $url)
    <li>

        // Echo url name
        {{ $url->url }} 

        // Here I need to list 2 reviews
        // Something like...
        @foreach ($url->reviews as $review)
            $review->text
        @endforeach

    </li>
    @endforeach
```

Do I have code generally set correctly?

**1.try** - this code in UrlController applies to urls, not its reviews.

```
$urls = URL::with('reviews')->orderBy('created_at')->take(2)->get();
```

**2.try**
This code will limit number of all fetched reviews, in this case only first url will receive review, while others will have zero.

```
 $urls = URL::with([
        'reviews' => function($q){
           $q->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
           $q->limit(2);
       }
       ])->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scope in your model:

```
public function scopeLatestFirst($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->limit(2);
}
```

And call:

```
@foreach ($url->reviews()->latestFirst()->get() as $review)
    $review->text
@endforeach
```

> More about [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: I get "Non-static method ... should not be called statically",when I place "static public function..." I get "Using $this when not in object context"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use limit in relation:

```
public function latestReviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->limit(2);
}
```

And then load this relation:

```
$urls = URL::with('latestReviews')->get();
```

Comment: Hm it doesn't change anything. if I intentionally place a typo it breaks (just checking if this is calling correctly everything), but it still fetches all reviews. It also doesn't change anything if I change orderby to asc or desc .